# SPO - User stuck in "Classic Experience" on some sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, classic-experience

All settings are defaults (so it should prefer Modern), I even changed one list explicitly to Modern but it still shows as Classic for her. When she clicks the "Exit classic experience" link it just refreshes the page, but it's still in Classic.

Cleared her cache entirely, tried different browsers, same behavior. No other user is experiencing this, and it's on a handful of sites she uses (but not all).

What should we look into next?

[This question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/259244/some-users-unable-to-change-back-from-classic-experience-to-modern-experience) sounds similar, but this is a site collection, there's no parent site above it.

Comment: Have you done some custom code in this site? I have changed the master page of a site, and a similar issue has appeared.

Comment: No custom code here, actually have a policy against code and modifying the master page